# Static library built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: c++, macos, static-libraries, unix-ar

I am experiencing what seems to be the same problem when I try to compile two different programs. Each of them creates first a static library and then the main application linking that library. I am working on Mac OS Mavericks with gcc 4.7.2.

**Program 1**

This is what is happening when I run `make`:

First, the library `libfeat.a` is created, but I get a warning:

```
ar rc ../lib/libfeat.a imgfeatures.o utils.o sift.o kdtree.o minpq.o xform.o
ranlib  ../lib/libfeat.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: ../lib/libfeat.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

Then, when compiling the application, it says that it cannot use the library because it wasn't built for the same architecture (x86_64):

```
gcc -O3 -I../include `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --cflags gsl` siftfeat.c -o ../bin/siftfeat -L../lib -lfeat `pkg-config --libs opencv` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gsl`
ld: warning: ignoring file ../lib/libfeat.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../lib/libfeat.a
```

If I run `lipo`, I get this:

```
$ lipo -info ../lib/libfeat.a 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: archive with no architecture specification: ../lib/libfeat.a (can't determine architecture for it)
```

**Program 2**

I am experiencing the same problem with a different program that does the same: creating a library first and using it later.

This is the output when creating the lib:

```
ar crv libsba.v1.5.a sba_levmar.o sba_levmar_wrap.o sba_lapack.o sba_crsm.o sba_chkjac.o
r - sba_levmar.o
r - sba_levmar_wrap.o
r - sba_lapack.o
r - sba_crsm.o
r - sba_chkjac.o
ranlib libsba.v1.5.a
```

This is the application:

```
c++ -o bundler -O3 -Wall -fpermissive  -I../lib/imagelib -I../lib/sfm-driver -I../lib/matrix -I../lib/5point -I../lib/sba-1.5 -I../lib/ann_1.1_char/include  -L../lib -L../lib/ann_1.1_char/lib \
    -D__NO_UI__ -D__BUNDLER__ -D__BUNDLER_DISTR__ BaseApp.o BundlerApp.o keys.o Register.o Epipolar.o Bundle.o BundleFast.o MatchTracks.o Camera.o Geometry.o ImageData.o SifterUtil.o BaseGeometry.o BundlerGeometry.o BoundingBox.o BundleAdd.o ComputeTracks.o BruteForceSearch.o BundleIO.o ProcessBundle.o BundleTwo.o Decompose.o RelativePose.o Distortion.o TwoFrameModel.o LoadJPEG.o -limage -lsfmdrv -lsba.v1.5 -lmatrix -lz -llapack -lblas -lcblas -lminpack -lm -l5point -ljpeg -lANN_char -lgfortran
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file ../lib/libsba.v1.5.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

In this case, `lipo` does tell me that the architecture of the library is x86_64:

```
$ lipo -info lib/libsba.v1.5.a 
input file lib/libsba.v1.5.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: lib/libsba.v1.5.a is architecture: x86_64
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [this question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663645/ignoring-file-lib-a-file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-be/20664949), I could look into this problem. I don't have much experience with static libraries, but I'll try to explain the problem.

For some reason, Mac OSX `ar` utility creates "subdirectories" in the static library. For example, building the `sba` library, the steps of `make` to build the static library from the object file is:

```
ar crv libsba.v1.5.a sba_levmar.o sba_levmar_wrap.o sba_lapack.o sba_crsm.o sba_chkjac.o
```

After that, if I look at the contents of the static library, I saw that in addition to the files, there are some strange directorios:

```
$ ar -t libsba.v1.5.a 
__.SYMDEF
/
//
sba_levmar.o/
/0
sba_lapack.o/
sba_crsm.o/
sba_chkjac.o/
sba_levmar.o
sba_levmar_wrap.o
sba_lapack.o
sba_crsm.o
sba_chkjac.o
sba_levmar.o
sba_levmar_wrap.o
sba_lapack.o
sba_crsm.o
sba_chkjac.o
```

If we try to extract those files, we get some errors regarding the subdirectories:

```
$ ar -x libsba.v1.5.a 
ar: /: Is a directory
ar: //: Is a directory
ar: sba_levmar.o/: Not a directory
ar: /0: Permission denied
ar: sba_lapack.o/: Not a directory
ar: sba_crsm.o/: Not a directory
ar: sba_chkjac.o/: Not a directory
```

Now, if we create the lib again with the extracted object files, it will work:

```
$ ar crv libsba.v1.5.a lib_o/*.o
a - lib_o/sba_chkjac.o
a - lib_o/sba_crsm.o
a - lib_o/sba_lapack.o
a - lib_o/sba_levmar.o
a - lib_o/sba_levmar_wrap.o

$ ar -t libsba.v1.5.a
__.SYMDEF SORTED
sba_chkjac.o
sba_crsm.o
sba_lapack.o
sba_levmar.o
sba_levmar_wrap.o
```

I don't understand the reason at all, but it worked for me.

Comment: Try using libtool instead of ar. According to Apple's libtool man page: "Libtool will not put any non-object input file into the output library (unlike ranlib, which allows this in the archives it operates on) [...]. Libtool with -static is intended to replace ar(5) and ranlib.".

Answer (score 32):

A possible cause is using the GNU `ar(1)`/`ranlib(1)` instead of the ones supplied by the Xcode toolchain. Run `which -a ar` and `which -a ranlib` to see the what you have in `$PATH`.

For example:

```
$ which -a ranlib
/usr/local/bin/ranlib
/usr/bin/ranlib

$ /usr/local/bin/ranlib --version
GNU ranlib (GNU Binutils) 2.28.51.20170105
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.

$ /usr/bin/ralib --version
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: unknown option character `-' in: --version
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib [-sactfqLT] [-] archive [...]
```

Same for `ar`. If you're like me and had `/usr/local/bin` preceeding `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`, with the GNU tools in `/usr/local/bin` and the Xcode ones in `/usr/bin`, you can fix it with:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
mv ar gar
ln -s /usr/bin/ar ar
mv ranlib granlib
ln -s /usr/bin/ranlib ranlib
```

Comment: Thanks! You can also just do `brew unlink binutils`.

Comment: This is incredibly irritating, and I don’t understand **why** this behaves in such a way. Do you happen to know? Apparently the two versions of `ar` produce different archives, but why/how? In fact, GNU `ar` doesn’t seem to produce a symbol index, even when invoked with `-s`, and GNU `ranlib` doesn’t add it either.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know. Maybe something related to mach-o? If you figure out a reason, it'd be a welcome addition to the answer.

Comment: @Timmmm, God bless you, dude! You saved my week!

Comment: In case you still need binutils, you can change the env path: 
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin". 
Note that $PATH must precede the binutils path.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `binutils` installed just unlink or uninstall it

```
brew unlink binutils
```

Comment: mac, and try to make grpc_php_plugin.  thank you for saving my day.

Answer (score 4):

Using `libtool -static -a` might be simpler to get working static library.

[Static library link issue with Mac OS X: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948807/static-library-link-issue-with-mac-os-x-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x8)

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem of getting the wrong architecture error message. It said the following:

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file blah/lib/blahblah.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

lipo gives: Non-fat file: ../lib/blahblah.a is architecture: x86_64

in the makefile it said the following:
     ARCH_FLAG =  -arch x86_64 -arch i386

I commented out the i386 part and the error disappeared.
     ARCH_FLAG =  -arch x86_64 #-arch i386

So, I think it is possible you are getting the error for the same reason.  Maybe you just need to set the architecture class to match your library.

By the way, my makefile was generated by swig, and I had not set any switches for the compiler.